# how to access Activity's instance variable from Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity such that when the user `onPause()` on that activity, i start a pending intent that modifies some variable such as `mSomeIntegerThatNeedsToBeReset` after some time (using Alarm Manager and pending intents).

I tried to make this variable static, which works, but i don't want to make things static if i can help it, and i need to reset that value (in activity) from somewhere else.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private Integer mSomeIntegerThatNeedsToBeReset;
}
```

what's the standard way to access this variable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "background activity"

Comment: @JoxTraex sure, i'll make that edit. do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either need to bind your service to your activity OR
You could dispatch an Intent from your service to your Activity and clear the state variable.